# Daily persistence with Amazon Alexa and DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an Alexa skill, and I need daily persistence. That means that I want to reset the values saved on the dynamo database every day, but I have no idea on how do this, and I have already searched everywhere. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could write a Lambda function to clear your table. You would call that Lambda function once a day from CloudWatch alarm.

Comment: Amazon added [ttl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) recently, you can specify a key that you then populate with a timestamp for when you want the row deleted. The best part is, the deletions don't use your provisioned throughput.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon added [ttl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) recently, you can specify a key that you then populate with a timestamp for when you want the row deleted. So depending on your use case you could have each row expire after a period of time, or set all rows to expire at a certain time daily. The deletes do not use your provisioned throughput, and it saves you the overhead of writing code to sweep your table daily.